PyO3 passing trait-implementers to functions in Rust
I recently started binding my Rust library to Python using PyO3, and so far it's been working very nicely. However, I have a structural issue I need to solve. I have a class with a method like:
fn register(&mut self, sum_name: &str, group_name: &str, amplitude: &Arc<RwLock<Amplitude>>) {...}

where Amplitude is a struct:
pub struct Amplitude {
    pub name: String,
    pub node: Box<dyn Node>,
}

impl Amplitude {
    pub fn new<N: Node + 'static>(name: &str, node: N) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            node: Box::new(node),
    }
}

I'm wondering how to bind this with PyO3. I have a bunch of structs which implement Node, and Amplitude kind of acts as a wrapper for the trait. I saw solutions here, here, and here, but I'm still a bit confused on how to implement this for my code.
Edit for clarification:
I think my question is better put this way: I have two Rust crates, a base crate with all the trait definitions, and another crate with the actual structs and implementations of that trait. I would like the users of my library to be able to write their own crates in Rust which use this trait (that's not a problem), but I also want them to be able to write a quick #[pyclass] on top of them to export a python module that will be able to interact with mine. Is this possible?

What don't you understand in the solution I suggested here?

@ChayimFriedman yours was my favorite, but I’m just curious as to how I make the API look nice on the Python side. Mostly the part about multiple constructors for the wrapper struct. Do I have to enumerate all of the potential structs which implement Node? I want to allow users to add their own in separate modules

@ChayimFriedman actually I think I may have figured it out thanks to your answer, I might post a self-answer here in a bit, but I have to make sure it works first.

You will have to enumerate them all. If you want to allow customizing them, you can have a CustomNode Python class that calls Python methods for the trait methods and then users can inherit it.

@ChayimFriedman Gotcha, yeah I think I'm gonna have to refactor some stuff, but I believe I have the right direction now, thanks
